# Pax-exam Karaf secure Maven repository authentication

Tags: java, maven, ssl, apache-karaf, pax-exam

I've got a karaf integration test based on pax-exam and need to access a secure maven repository:

```
editConfigurationFilePut("etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg", "org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories", "https://my.repo.net:443/nexus/content/groups/my-group@snapshots@id=my.repo")
```

Unsecured works fine, however I've troubles getting the ssl authentication working:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

So I'd normally either provide a *truststore* with the key and/or pass it in using environment variables. The problem is, in this configuration the environment variables are not being passed to the container, so where could I hook the SSL certs into my karaf instance?

Answer (score 0):

VMOption allows you to pass variables to the karaf container like this:

```
new VMOption("-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=my.truststore")
```